# How to create custom rounding in PHP?

Tags: php

I am trying to make an algorithm that will round according to these conditions:

- 1 or 2 cents - rounded down to "0"
- 3 or 4 cents - rounds up to 5 cents
- 5 cents - 5 cents left
- 6 or 7 cents - rounds down to 5 cents
- 8 or 9 cents - rounds up to "0"

So, it should look like this:

```
PRICE| AFTER
9.90 | 9.90
9.91 | 9.90
9.92 | 9.90
9.93 | 9.95
9.94 | 9.95
9.95 | 9.95
9.96 | 9.95
9.97 | 9.95
9.98 | 10.0
9.99 | 10.0
10.0 | 10.0
```

My code is here, but looks strange.
For numbers like 10.99 result becomes 10.10:

```
 function roundDown(float $price): float
    {
        [$number, $decimals] = explode('.', sprintf('%.2f', $price));
        [, $second] = str_split($decimals);

        $table = [
            0 => 0,
            1 => -1,
            2 => -2,
            3 => 2,
            4 => 1,
            5 => 0,
            6 => -1,
            7 => -2,
            8 => 2,
            9 => 1,
        ];

        return $number . '.' . str_pad((float)$decimals+(float)$table[$second], 2, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
    }
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Sorry, updated.

Comment: What do you mean "Not working for numbers without decimals?" You are rounding more-or-less to the nearest `.05`. So feeding a whole number would just spit back the whole number, if your code is working as your requirements describe. Can you share what your expected output of a number-without-decimal would be?

Comment: Q: Would Richard Dobroň's solution work for you?  If "Yes", please "Upvote" (triangle icon) and "Accept" his answer.  Q: What about values like 9.50?  9.47?  9.52?

Comment: Richard's solution is exactly what I was looking for, thanks for the help guys!

Answer (score 1):

You have forgotten to *carry the hundreds* when you reach 100: `1.99 + 0.01` needs to become `2.00`

Sticking to your current approach, you could check if the new "decimals" reach 100 or higher after your adj, and if so increment the "number":

```
function roundDown(float $price): float
{
    [$number, $decimals] = explode('.', sprintf('%.2f', $price));
    [, $second] = str_split($decimals);

    $table = [
        0 => 0,
        1 => -1,
        2 => -2,
        3 => 2,
        4 => 1,
        5 => 0,
        6 => -1,
        7 => -2,
        8 => 2,
        9 => 1,
    ];

    $newDecimals = (float)$decimals+(float)$table[$second];
    if ( $newDecimals > 99 ) {
        $number += 1;
        $newDecimals -= 100;
    }
    return $number . '.' . str_pad($newDecimals, 2, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
}
```

(There are various other ways to improve the code, or implement the requirement a different way, but I wanted to point out the specific bug in your current attempt, and the simplest change that fixes it.)

Answer (score 0):

I would avoid the string manipulation at the end and set the values in $table to be the actuals values to be added or subtracted and then do the arithmetic at the end.

```
function roundDown(float $price): float
{
    [$number, $decimals] = explode('.', sprintf('%.2f', $price));
    [, $second] = str_split($decimals);

    $table = [
        0 => 0,
        1 => -0.01,
        2 => -0.02,
        3 => 0.02,
        4 => 0.01,
        5 => 0,
        6 => -0.01,
        7 => -0.02,
        8 => 0.02,
        9 => 0.01,
    ];

    return $price + $table[$second];
}
```

Comment: You're correct: I would definitely avoid string manipulation :)

Comment: This feels a bit half-way between two approaches: you're still doing string manipulation rather than arithmetic to _choose_ the increment.